# Why is the code giving output of -61 when I do cout c but 195 when I cout a+b?

Tags: c++, char, output

I wrote the following code, I do not understand why I get -61 when I cout<<int(c).

```
int main() {
char a= 'a';
char b= 'b';
char c= a+b;
cout<<int(a)<<" ";
cout<<int(b)<<" ";
cout<<int(a+b)<<" ";
cout<<int(c)<<" ";
return 0;
```

}

```
**OUTPUT**
97 98 195 -61
```

Comment: Signed char with the range -128..127 overflow.

Comment: @S.M. please create an answer and elaborate.

Comment: On a platform with different encoding you'll get different output.  For example, in EBCDIC (which the encoding was strongly influenced by Hollerith punch cards) `'a'` is 129 and `'b'` is 130 and `char` will have unsigned behavior unless the compiler is flagged to treat `char` as signed.  Adding them results in 259, modulo 256 = 3.

Answer (score 0):

char type may be signed or unsigned. It is tuned by a compiler flag. Char type is signed by default in most compilers and consists of 8 bits, one bit is for sign and 7 bits are for a numeric values. Thus the signed char represents numeric values from -128 up till 127. Such set of values is a ring. Further increasing of 127 returns to -128.

As you see, 97 and 98 are ASCII codes of 'a' and 'b'. Any types smaller than int are promoted to int before applying operators, thus a+b is int 195. If you assign 195 to a signed char, the signed value overflow happens, that is considered as the undefined behaviour, because signed values may be represented differently than above. In you case, 195 is over 127 on 68, since127+1 is -128, thus 127+68 127+1+67 is -128+67 is -61.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have `operator+(char,char)`. Therefore when you add two `char`s the arguments are promoted to `int`s and result is `int`.

Further initializing a `char` c with `int` (value `195`) that is outside of range of `char` of your compiler (seems  to be `-128` ... `127`) is implementation defined behavior by C++ standard.

On your implementation the behavior looks common ... so effectively for values `x > 127` the result is `x - 256`. The `195 - 256` is value `-61`.

If you want 8 bit integer that can have `195` in range you should use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.